# parametric equations for two point

Tags: vectors

I found the parallel vector between $A(2,4,-3)$ and $B(3,-1,1)$ is equal to let's say $V(3-2,-1-4,1-(-3))=V(1,-5,4)$

now how can i find the parametric equation for the line that passes through that two point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: For any two vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ the line $\vec{r}(t) = \vec{A}+t(\vec{B}-\vec{A})$ passes through $\vec{r}(0) = \vec{A}$ and $\vec{r}(1) = \vec{B}$. Can you apply this to your problem?

Comment: yes i try it to apply this and i found the ans

Comment: one more thing how can i find the point does the line intersect the x-y plane

Comment: The $xy$-plane consists of all points whose $z$-coordinate is $0$. So, set the third component of the parametric equation for the line equal to $0$ and solve for $t$. Then plug that value back in to get the point.

Comment: i found the ans thank you i  appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the parametric equation of the line passing through the two points $A(2, 4, -3)$ & $(3, -1, 1)$ is given as  $$\frac{x-2}{3-2}=\frac{y-4}{-1-4}=\frac{z-(-3)}{1-(-3)}=t$$ $$\frac{x-2}{1}=\frac{y-4}{-5}=\frac{z+3}{4}=t$$
$$x=t+2,\ y=-5t+4, \ z=4t-3$$
or $$\color{red}{r(t)\equiv t(1, -5, 4)+(2, 4, -3)}$$